# Two way upload image in ImageField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, request, urllib

I want to create widget for django-admin for upload images from url or use default file-input.

```
class ImageFieldFromUrlWidget(ClearableFileInput) :

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        base_content = super(ImageFieldFromUrlWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        ps_input = URLInput().render(name='ps_%s'%name, value='', attrs={})
        return mark_safe(ps_input + base_content)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if data.get('ps_%s' % name, False) :
            import io, requests
            from urllib import request
            raw_image = requests.get(data.get('ps_%s' % name)).content
            new_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(io.BytesIO(raw_image), name, 'temp.jpg', 'jpeg', None, None)
            return new_file
        return super(ImageFieldFromUrlWidget, self).value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
```

I want to download file and put it to files-array for process default save.
But when I send data, I get the error "`The submitted file is empty`".

How do this? Any ideas?

PS I need to control get-request, for download image (set cookie)